# Webpart changes only affect my user (SharePoint 3.0)

Tags: wss-3.0

I have to support a SharePoint 3.0 Intranet Site for internal news / appointments and so on.

I kept it simple and havent used any code or the SharePointDesigner, because its not a really big thing, just get the latest company news in a small text.

So everythings allright until now. I have a start page with some List Views. I have set the maximum entry count to 3 for all those webparts some weeks ago. Everyone who access the site got 3 entries.

Now I did some other changes on the WebParts (entry count, the visibility and position etc..) but the changes are only made on my account. Why is that? Can somebody help me on this? I cant find anything online.

EDIT: If my co worker (he has also admin permissions) wants to change a webpart, theres a error that show up:

The file is currently checked out by another user or closed for editing.

But the site isnt checked out and no one is editing it. I dont understand it..

Comment: btw: Im admin on this sharepoint site and the users from our AD are logged onto the site automatically. theres a admin group and a member group. But the changes I made some weeks ago affected all the users, not just me.

Answer (score 0):

There are  two ways to update list view, One is you can go to list setting >> list view and make your changes and another way is you can simply edit your webpart and make changes done.

If you will go with first approach then again you will have to come to the page and edit page >> edit list view webpart >> select respective listview >>  publish the page.

If you will go with second approach then you can edit page >> edit list view webpart >> Edit current view >> mmake your changes >> publish the page.

In both the ways you will  get your changes reflected to all the users.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I make all the changes exactly like your second approach. I click Edit Page -> Edit the ListViewWebPart. Then I do my changes in the properties window on the right and say OK. The changes are made for my user. But when another user is looking at the Site/WebPart, its still the "old version". That has worked for years now and suddenly it stops and I dont have a clue why.. :(

Comment: I also cleared the browser cache, no solution..

Comment: Did you publish that page?

Comment: See my own answer: the default.aspx was checked out for what reason ever.. I think I just wanted to test something and forgot to check in again. Thanks for your support :)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution:
I have checked out the default.aspx in my SharePoint Designer (which I used only for testing some things) and forgot to check it in again after the tests. Damn boy...